# How to create a model for pictures from Unsplash?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to use the Unsplash API to display a list of pictures that come to me, the title and the author. The problem is that I do not understand how to create a model for converting JSON that comes to me so that I can get the picture, author and title. JSON has nested elements and I don't understand how to do it. How can i do this?
My JSON for one picture:

```js
 {
      "id":"RBo6ayiFND0",
      "created_at":"2022-07-08T13:04:40-04:00",
      "updated_at":"2022-07-22T00:20:05-04:00",
      "promoted_at":null,
      "width":4160,
      "height":6240,
      "color":"#c0c0c0",
      "blur_hash":"LPIOLgtR%1IT~qsSMxxZx]V@s.RP",
      "description":null,
      "alt_description":null,
      "urls":{
         "raw":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299156528-2d50a9a6a444?ixid=MnwzNDg3MDF8MXwxfGFsbHwxfHx8fHx8Mnx8MTY1ODQ4ODUyOQ\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1",
         "full":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299156528-2d50a9a6a444?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MnwzNDg3MDF8MXwxfGFsbHwxfHx8fHx8Mnx8MTY1ODQ4ODUyOQ\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80",
         "regular":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299156528-2d50a9a6a444?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MnwzNDg3MDF8MXwxfGFsbHwxfHx8fHx8Mnx8MTY1ODQ4ODUyOQ\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080",
         "small":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299156528-2d50a9a6a444?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MnwzNDg3MDF8MXwxfGFsbHwxfHx8fHx8Mnx8MTY1ODQ4ODUyOQ\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=400",
         "thumb":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299156528-2d50a9a6a444?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MnwzNDg3MDF8MXwxfGFsbHwxfHx8fHx8Mnx8MTY1ODQ4ODUyOQ\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=200",
         "small_s3":"https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images.unsplash.com/small/photo-1657299156528-2d50a9a6a444"
      },
      "links":{
         "self":"https://api.unsplash.com/photos/RBo6ayiFND0",
         "html":"https://unsplash.com/photos/RBo6ayiFND0",
         "download":"https://unsplash.com/photos/RBo6ayiFND0/download?ixid=MnwzNDg3MDF8MXwxfGFsbHwxfHx8fHx8Mnx8MTY1ODQ4ODUyOQ",
         "download_location":"https://api.unsplash.com/photos/RBo6ayiFND0/download?ixid=MnwzNDg3MDF8MXwxfGFsbHwxfHx8fHx8Mnx8MTY1ODQ4ODUyOQ"
      },
      "categories":[
         
      ],
      "likes":21,
      "liked_by_user":false,
      "current_user_collections":[
         
      ],
      "sponsorship":{
         "impression_urls":[
            "https://secure.insightexpressai.com/adServer/adServerESI.aspx?script=false\u0026bannerID=10624831\u0026rnd=[timestamp]\u0026redir=https://secure.insightexpressai.com/adserver/1pixel.gif"
         ],
         "tagline":"Wholesome crispbread from Sweden",
         "tagline_url":"https://www.wasa.com/global/",
         "sponsor":{
            "id":"5tdWPtk6hBg",
            "updated_at":"2022-07-22T06:53:49-04:00",
            "username":"wasacrispbread",
            "name":"Wasa Crispbread",
            "first_name":"Wasa Crispbread",
            "last_name":null,
            "twitter_username":null,
            "portfolio_url":"https://www.wasa.com/global/",
            "bio":"Things we love:\r\n Crispbread (naturally)   Our planet   Delicious food, everyday",
            "location":null,
            "links":{
               "self":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread",
               "html":"https://unsplash.com/@wasacrispbread",
               "photos":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/photos",
               "likes":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/likes",
               "portfolio":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/portfolio",
               "following":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/following",
               "followers":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/followers"
            },
            "profile_image":{
               "small":"https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1655151625963-f0eec015f2a4image?ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026crop=faces\u0026fit=crop\u0026w=32\u0026h=32",
               "medium":"https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1655151625963-f0eec015f2a4image?ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026crop=faces\u0026fit=crop\u0026w=64\u0026h=64",
               "large":"https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1655151625963-f0eec015f2a4image?ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026crop=faces\u0026fit=crop\u0026w=128\u0026h=128"
            },
            "instagram_username":"wasacrispbread",
            "total_collections":0,
            "total_likes":0,
            "total_photos":73,
            "accepted_tos":true,
            "for_hire":false,
            "social":{
               "instagram_username":"wasacrispbread",
               "portfolio_url":"https://www.wasa.com/global/",
               "twitter_username":null,
               "paypal_email":null
            }
         }
      },
      "topic_submissions":{
         
      },
      "user":{
         "id":"5tdWPtk6hBg",
         "updated_at":"2022-07-22T06:53:49-04:00",
         "username":"wasacrispbread",
         "name":"Wasa Crispbread",
         "first_name":"Wasa Crispbread",
         "last_name":null,
         "twitter_username":null,
         "portfolio_url":"https://www.wasa.com/global/",
         "bio":"Things we love:\r\n Crispbread (naturally)   Our planet   Delicious food, everyday",
         "location":null,
         "links":{
            "self":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread",
            "html":"https://unsplash.com/@wasacrispbread",
            "photos":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/photos",
            "likes":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/likes",
            "portfolio":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/portfolio",
            "following":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/following",
            "followers":"https://api.unsplash.com/users/wasacrispbread/followers"
         },
         "profile_image":{
            "small":"https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1655151625963-f0eec015f2a4image?ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026crop=faces\u0026fit=crop\u0026w=32\u0026h=32",
            "medium":"https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1655151625963-f0eec015f2a4image?ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026crop=faces\u0026fit=crop\u0026w=64\u0026h=64",
            "large":"https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1655151625963-f0eec015f2a4image?ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026crop=faces\u0026fit=crop\u0026w=128\u0026h=128"
         },
         "instagram_username":"wasacrispbread",
         "total_collections":0,
         "total_likes":0,
         "total_photos":73,
         "accepted_tos":true,
         "for_hire":false,
         "social":{
            "instagram_username":"wasacrispbread",
            "portfolio_url":"https://www.wasa.com/global/",
            "twitter_username":null,
            "paypal_email":null
         }
      }
   },
```

Picture Model:

```js
class PictureModel {
  const PictureModel({});
  
  factory PictureModel.fromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) {
    return PictureModel(
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried converters like JSON to dart?

Comment: Yes, I have already created such models. The problem I have is that I don't know how to get the image from the nesting. How to spell it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you only need:

- image
- title (I'll assume this is `description`)
- author (I'll assume this is `user.name`)

You can create the `PictureModel` as follows:

```
class PictureModel {
  final String author;
  final String? title;
  final String imageUrl;
  
  const PictureModel({
    required this.author,
    this.title,
    required this.imageUrl,
  });

  factory PictureModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PictureModel(
      author: json['user']['name'],
      title: json['description'],
      imageUrl: json['urls']['regular'], 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you meant something like below by saying nested.

To simplify it, let's use Photo and Urls properties

```
class Photo {
  Photo({
    this.id,
    this.urls,
    ...
  });

  String? id;
  Urls? urls;
  ...

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return Photo(
        id: json['id'],
        urls: Urls.fromJson(json['urls']),
        ...
      );
    
  }
}
```

Then Urls object.

```
class Urls {
  Urls({
    this.rawUrl,
    this.fullUrl,
    this.regularUrl,
    this.smallUrl,
    this.thumbUrl,
    this.smallS3Url,
  });

  String? rawUrl;
  String? fullUrl;
  String? regularUrl;
  String? smallUrl;
  String? thumbUrl;
  String? smallS3Url;

  factory Urls.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Urls(
        rawUrl: json['raw'],
        fullUrl: json['full'],
        regularUrl: json['regular'],
        smallUrl: json['small'],
        thumbUrl: json['thumb'],
        smallS3Url: json['small_s3'],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'rawUrl': rawUrl,
        'fullUrl': fullUrl,
        'regularUrl': regularUrl,
        'smallUrl': smallUrl,
        'thumbUrl': thumbUrl,
        'smallS3Url': smallS3Url,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply you can use any **JSON to Dart** tool, that takes the JSON and returns a dart model like [this one](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).
2. Or you can do it manually by making nested classes.
   firstly you will make a parent class that contains the first level of the JSON file and each element containing other elements inside will be a separate class and you will use it as a type of the element.

so if we took the first level of the file and one other element from the second level such as the element `user` your code will be something like this:

```
class Pic {
   Pic.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    promotedAt = json['promoted_at'];
    width = json['width'];
    height = json['height'];
    color = json['color'];
    blurHash = json['blur_hash'];
    description = json['description'];
    altDescription = json['alt_description'];
    urls = Urls.fromJson(json['urls']);
    links = Links.fromJson(json['links']);
    if (json['categories'] != null) {
      categories = [];
      json['categories'].forEach((v) {
        categories?.add(Categories.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    likes = json['likes'];
    likedByUser = json['liked_by_user'];
    if (json['current_user_collections'] != null) {
      currentUserCollections = [];
      json['current_user_collections'].forEach((v) {
        currentUserCollections?.add(CurrentUserCollections.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    sponsorship = json['sponsorship'] != null ? Sponsorship.fromJson(json['sponsorship']) : null;
    topicSubmissions = json['topic_submissions'];
    user = User.fromJson(json['user']);
  }
  String? id;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  dynamic promotedAt;
  int? width;
  int? height;
  String? color;
  String? blurHash;
  dynamic description;
  dynamic altDescription;
  Urls? urls;
  Links? links;
  List<dynamic>? categories;
  int? likes;
  bool? likedByUser;
  List<dynamic>? currentUserCollections;
  Sponsorship? sponsorship;
  dynamic topicSubmissions;
  User? user;
}

class User {
  User.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    username = json['username'];
    name = json['name'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    twitterUsername = json['twitter_username'];
    portfolioUrl = json['portfolio_url'];
    bio = json['bio'];
    location = json['location'];
    links = json['links'] != null ? Links.fromJson(json['links']) : null;
    profileImage = json['profile_image'] != null ? ProfileImage.fromJson(json['profile_image']) : null;
    instagramUsername = json['instagram_username'];
    totalCollections = json['total_collections'];
    totalLikes = json['total_likes'];
    totalPhotos = json['total_photos'];
    acceptedTos = json['accepted_tos'];
    forHire = json['for_hire'];
    social = json['social'] != null ? Social.fromJson(json['social']) : null;
  }
  String? id;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? username;
  String? name;
  String? firstName;
  dynamic lastName;
  dynamic twitterUsername;
  String? portfolioUrl;
  String? bio;
  dynamic location;
  Links? links;
  ProfileImage? profileImage;
  String? instagramUsername;
  int? totalCollections;
  int? totalLikes;
  int? totalPhotos;
  bool? acceptedTos;
  bool? forHire;
  Social? social;
}
```

notice that each element that contains other elements inside is with a special data type like `Urls` `Links` `Sponsorship` `User` in the first class, and `Links` `ProfileImage` `Social` in the second class. so each of these data types is a class on its own but I only mentioned the class `User` to let you continue the rest of the code.
Happy Coding ;)